# Programatically manipulating the Eclipse RCP EditorArea Sashes

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I have an eclipse RCP application that uses and Editor Area.  I have a few things that I would like to do programatically but cannot find any documentation:

1) Do not restore editor sash layout.   I.e., I like to use rcp saveAndRestore functionality, but for my perspectives, views, and other momentos.  I do not however want to restore the editor area multiple tab groups at all.  I choose not to implement the IPersistableEditor interface, and therefore my editor sessions are not restored, but when my application restarts, it still has split windows (swt sashes for multiple tab groups), etc, and i wish it was just 1 editor area tab group like default.

2) I would like to programaticaly split/duplicate an editor into another tab group, for example I would like a button that says "Split Horizontal" and that opens a new editor in a new tab group beside the current one.

Any help is much appreciated!  Happy Coding!

/P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Funny, seems like a bug in the platform.
You can explicitly close all editors upon workbench window close. One option to do this would be to override the preWindowShellClose method in your WorkbenchWindowAdvisor:

```java
public class ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor extends WorkbenchWindowAdvisor {
    @Override
    public boolean preWindowShellClose() {
        getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getActivePage().closeAllEditors(true);
        return super.preWindowShellClose();
    }
}
```

If you don't have access to the ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor, you can try to do the same with the IPerspectiveListenerX

2) I think there is no public API for this. The editor area behavior is defined in the presentation factory (see org.eclipse.ui.presentationFactories extension-point). You could clone the RCP standard presentation and implement the desired split-editor-area-on-demand functionality.